# Mysql query using variables to find three consecutive numbers

Tags: mysql

Write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively. The table contains id and Num columns. Num column values should be consecutive.

I am using three varialbes: tert, prev and current to store the three consecutive numbers. However, the following code does not give the right output. I want to know why?

```
SELECT if((@tert := @prev) = (@prev: = @current) = (@current := Num),Num,'') as ConsecutiveNums
FROM
  Logs,
  (SELECT @current := -10, @prev := -1, @tert = -1) init
```

Comment: What column indicates the order in the table?

Comment: See the edit, it answers your question.

Comment: `2=2=2` does not evaluate to true because `2=2=2` => `1=2` => `0`. so it doesn't work. maybe use `(2=2)*(2=2)*(2=2)`

Comment: I can try 2=2 and 2=2, but are short-circuit there in Mysql? How do I avoid short circuit in Mysql?

What do you mean by *?

Comment: i made an edit, you can try `*` instead of `and`